# Auto increment abstract base class's typeid

Tags: c#, dictionary

So I have a `Dictionary<Type, ...>` that has become the bottleneck in a tight loop. I'd like to do away with using `Type` as the key. I'm lucky enough that all the types that end up as a key in this dictionary implement a specific interface that I have access to changing, and I think I'd like to change it to an abstract base class.

I think what I'm ultimately trying to do is have something like this:

```
public abstract class MyBaseType
{
   public virtual int TypeId { get; }
}
```

Then I would go about having the derived classes from this auto increment the TypeId somehow. Is this possible in an automatic manner? So I don't have to specifically set a number for each one?

What I'm trying to avoid:

```
public class MyDerived : MyBaseType
{
   public override int TypeId => 0;
}

public class MyDerived2: MyBaseTYpe
{
   public override int TypeId => 1;
} 
...etc
```

Any ideas?

Edit:
It's the lookup on type that is causing my bottleneck. Would changing this to a type besides `Type` actually gain me anything? Is it even likely that it's because of `GetHashCode()` on `Type` that I'm bottlenecking in the first place?

Edit again:
I've narrowed down the most expensive part to be exactly where I thought it was, in the dictionary index operator:
[image: Profiler]

Comment: have you tried to use typeof(T).FullName as key instead of Type class itself?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why, but this actually slows it down more. With `Type` as the key the loop takes ~42ms, with `String` it takes around ~72. Very suprising. This tells me it may actually be the typeof() that could be taking longer. I can't seem to profile at a deeper level at this point, but if I figure out exactly which part it is i'll report back.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the Dictionary<Type, ...> was the bottleneck?

Comment: @MelGerats Using the profiler I saw that the majority of the time spent was in a method that only had a dictionary lookup inside it. This is still the case, but I don't think it will get much faster than it is by swapping data types further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible in an automatic manner? So I don't have to specifically set a number for each one?

No.

> Would changing this to a type besides `Type` actually gain me anything?

Why don't you try and find out? Setting up a simple test where you compare different key performances is rather straightforward.

If you bothered to do it you would see that an `int` key *will* perform better than a `Type` key; performance is slightly more than twice faster in the case of an `int`.

But the most meaningful result from the test is that in my machine, 1 677 000 lookups are performed in under 40 ms for ints, and slightly over 80 ms for types. That is simply blindingly fast (and don't forget those times include the test key lookup too). If thats your bottleneck then you need to begin thinking in parallelizing your work somehow.

Benchmark code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var d1 = new Dictionary<int, object>();
    var d2 = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    var keys1 = new List<int>();
    var keys2 = new List<Type>();            
    var counter = 0;
    var types = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(int)).GetTypes();

    foreach (var t in types)
    {
        d1.Add(counter, null);
        keys1.Add(counter++);
        d2.Add(t, null);
        keys2.Add(t);
    }

    //warmup run. JITTER
    benchMarkDictionary(d1, keys1);

    //good runs
    for (var repetition = 0; repetition < 10; repetition++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Test #{repetition} --------");
        Console.WriteLine($"int key: {benchMarkDictionary(d1, keys1)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"type key: {benchMarkDictionary(d2, keys2)}");
    }
}

static long benchMarkDictionary<TKey, TValue>(
    Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict,
    IList<TKey> keys)
{
    var count = dict.Count;
    TValue result = default(TValue);
    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();

    for (var lookups = 0; lookups < count * 1000; lookups++)
    {
        result = dict[keys[lookups % count]];
    }

    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    return watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the (very repetitive) work to get the key down to an int and the speed wasn't improved that much. What this tells me is that I just had unrealistic expectations of the cost of the work I was performing. I'll investigate threading as an alternative way to see improvements.